# Have to click twice for toggle in 1 function; Can click once in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

This function needs to be clicked twice to run:

```
function myFunction(IDofObject,IDofObject2) {
   $('#' + IDofObject).click(function(){
   $('#' + IDofObject2).toggle();
})};
```

This function only needs to be clicked once:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#show-hide2').click(function(){
    $('#content_0_contentmain_3_panelActiveCampaigns').toggle();
    if ($('#show-hide2').text() == 'Hide') {
        $('#show-hide2').text('Show');
    }
    else {
        $('#show-hide2').text('Hide');
    }
  });  
});
```

How can I make the first one work by clicking only once?

Answer (score 0):

If you add the click event handler to the document ready call it will bind to the element right away versus when the function is called. This means it will be called on the first click versus the second click because it need to have the initial function called before binding the click handler. To avoid this you can just have an onclick on the element you want to trigger the function from and have it act as the pre-bound click handler.

```
    <div id="IDofObject" onclick="myFunction(IDofObject2)"></div>

    function myFunction(IDofObject2) {
         $('#' + IDofObject2).toggle();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you don't need to specify ID of Object1, you only need ID of Object2, simply like this:

```
<button onclick="myFunction('some_div')">Show/hide</button>

function myFunction(ID) {
    $("#"+ID).toggle(); // or something
}
```

[See on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e86cL/)

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
function myFunction(IDofObject,IDofObject2) {
     $('#' + IDofObject).click(function(){
     $('#' + IDofObject2).toggle();
})};
```

by

```
function myFunction(IDofObject,IDofObject2) {
     $('#' + IDofObject2).toggle();
};
```